# Get only numeric values from a string

Tags: php, regex

I'm formatting the output of an SMTP server log for output on a secured website. I already formatted the IP addresses with and without added port numbers (123.123.123.123 and 123.123.123.123:456, `/\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\:\d{1,5}|\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}|\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}/`).

Now I need to format other numeric values, but not in combination with non-numeric characters like ID's and `CRAM-MD5`).

In the following example, I need to get the 100, 56, 0, but neither the 5 of `CRAM-MD5`, nor the 21 (or 21E9) of `21E9C126E0B80`, aAnd I need the 0 after `Client` and the 2022070508301657009855590.

```
2022-07-05 12:00:00 New Client Rejected (192.241.222.210 [digitalocean.com] -> AbuseIPDB Score: 100)
2022-07-05 12:00:00 New Client Connected (137.184.30.176 [digitalocean.com] -> AbuseIPDB Score: 56)
2022-07-05 12:00:00 New Client Connected (192.168.10.12 [] -> AbuseIPDB Score: 0)
2022-07-05 12:00:00 250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN CRAM-MD5
2022-07-05 12:00:00 250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 21E9C126E0B80
2022-07-05 12:00:00 Client 0 from 192.168.10.12 Disconnecting
2022-07-05 12:00:00 Forward mail 2022070508301657009855590
```

I currently have the following regex, which gets me `100` only: `/ [^a-zA-Z\/\.>(]\d+[^a-zA-Z\/\.>)\-]/`
Yes, I need a space in front and exclude the `>` to avoid formatting an already formatted string. And yes, there need to be some follow-up characters excluded.

Here is my code:

```php
preg_match_all('/\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\:\d{1,5}|\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}|\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}/', $sLog, $matches);
foreach ($matches[0] as $nr) {
$sLog = str_replace($nr, '<span class="number">' . $nr . '</span>', $sLog);
}
```

The test scenario is here: https://regex101.com/r/sbD10s/1.
The regex will be used inside `preg_match_all()`.

Can anyone help me on finding the correct regex?

Comment: Maybe `:\s+\K\d+(?=\))` will do? See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/8pRn7M/1).

Comment: Or, maybe parse the whole lines with something like `^(?<message>.*?)\s+\((?<ip>\d[\d.]*)\s+\[(?<host>[^][]*)]\s+->\s+(?<scorestring>.*?):\s+(?<scorevalue>\d+)\)`? See https://regex101.com/r/8pRn7M/2

Comment: Tried both, but they didn't find any of the numbers.

Comment: Can you provide a code demo? [Mine works](https://3v4l.org/EaGlB) and extracts all details. [Here is another (first) code demo](https://3v4l.org/SCOXS).

Comment: I already have in the question. So for your code I need to update the programming on the `preg_match_all()` result. I'll test that and get back here.

Comment: Yes, it works, but only for the `Score:` values. But I need all the numbers and therefore added 2 code lines (with a new regex101 link). Those were not found in both your solutions. Thanks for having another look!

Comment: Then why don't you want `250` in `250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN CRAM-MD5` and  `250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 21E9C126E0B80`?

Comment: Ok, if the match should start with a whitespace, try `preg_match_all('~(?<=\h)\d+\b(?!\.\d)~', $text, $matches)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246171/discussion-between-spider-it-and-wiktor-stribizew).

Comment: We prefer a [mcve] with clear, realistic input which reflects the most challenging fringe cases AND your exact desired output from the sample input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you wrap your matches with other strings, you should use `preg_replace` directly.

To match the numbers after whitespaces that are not followed with a dot + another digits, you can use `(?<=\h)\d+\b(?!\.\d)` pattern.

The whole solution for the current problem will look like

```php
$sLog = preg_replace('~\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,3}(?::\d{1,5})?)?~', '<span class="number">$0</span>', $sLog);
$sLog = preg_replace('~(?<=\h)\d+\b(?!\.\d)~', '<span>$0</span>', $sLog);
```

Please adjust the replacement pattern in the second `preg_replace` to your liking. If the replacements are identical to both, just merge the two patterns into a single one:

```php
$sLog = preg_replace('~\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,3}(?::\d{1,5})?)?|(?<=\h)\d+\b(?!\.\d)~', '<span class="number">$0</span>', $sLog);
```

See the [`(?<=\h)\d+\b(?!\.\d)` regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/aV2UYI/1):

- `(?<=\h)` - immediately to the left, there must be a horizontal whitespace
- `\d+` - one or more digits
- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(?!\.\d)` - immediately on the right, there must be no `.` and a digit.

Comment: Perfekt solution, just added the class in the second `preg_replace()` ;)